# How to Enable Guard Malloc

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, malloc

This is a stupid question. The documentation says:

To enable debugging using Guard Malloc, choose the Run > Enable Guard Malloc option in Xcode before running your project. Building and running your application with this option enabled runs your application using the Guard Malloc library automatically. You can use this option both Mac OS X applications and also for iPhone applications running in the simulator.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html

So yea yea go to Run > Enable Guard Malloc. There is no Run menu!!!!!

The menus are Xcode File Edit View Navigate Editor Product Window Help

There is no Run menu. So what the hell I should do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to your Schemes (via Product > Edit Scheme), then select the build configuration that you want, then navigate to the "Diagnostics" menu, and then check the "Enable Guard Malloc" checkbox:

[image]

Comment: You can get to Schemes via Product > Edit Scheme.

Comment: You can also just press option whilst clicking the run button